# Triggering a callback whenever Activerecord's :after_save callbacks trigger

Tags: ruby, activerecord, callback, scope

I have the following code, and i want to trigger FooClass's callbacks whenever ActiveRecord's `on_new_annoucement` triggers. I have making the callbacks array a class variable of the module but it's outside the scope of Activerecord's callback.

```
module FooModule
    class FooClass
        attr_reader :callbacks
        def initialize
            @@callbacks = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = [] }
        end

        def on_new_announcement(&block)
             @@callbacks[:on_new_announcement] << block
        end
     end

     class Announcement < ActiveRecord::Base
          after_save :on_new_announcement
          def on_new_announcement 
              ....
          end
     end
 end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code will only get messier over time with this approach.

Consider using [Wisper Gem](https://github.com/krisleech/wisper). It implements event-listeners pattern and helps you maintain clean code.